# PageSpeed Insights with Service Worker

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Our CMS is using an image service CDN that requires a few parameters added to the URL of an image to serve optimized formats(webp, avif...) when supported.
The parameters cannot be added directly on the CMS, so we are using a service worker to add them when we detect a supported image format.

The problem is that PageSpeed Insight test keeps saying that the images are not "next-gen" format and the URL is missing the parameters.

Is there any way to force the test to reload with the service worker installed? Is google using service workers in general to calculate performance stats?

Thanks!